# Pop up not showing! PHP echo+alert

Tags: php, echo, alert

Can someone explain to me why my alert is not working? It was fine some days ago, but suddenly it stopped showing, the thing is that only ONE is broken.

Please, see the code below, the "echo ..." inside the IF(){ does not work, while the "echo..." outside the IF(){ works.

I've lost count on how many times i got through this code and can't find anything!

Is there a better way to show a pop-up message to the user besides using echo+alert?

```
    <?php
        if ($cobrar_mensalidade === 'sim') {

            //sending email
                $mensagemHTMLinscrito = 'Hello';

                //headers
                $headers2 = "MIME-Version: 1.1" . $quebra_linha;
                $headers2 .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1". $quebra_linha;
                $headers2 .= "From: " . $emailSender . $quebra_linha;
                $headers2 .= "Return-Path: " . $emailSender . $quebra_linha;
                $headers2 .= "Reply-to: " .  $emailSender . $quebra_linha;

                //sending method
            mail($email, 'bla', $mensagemHTMLinscrito, $headers2, $emailSender);

            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Not working');</script>";

            header("Location: http://www.blabla.com");
            die("just die");
        }


        //sending email for other people

                $mensagemHTMLinscrito = 'bla bla';

                //headers
                $headers2 = "MIME-Version: 1.1" . $quebra_linha;
                $headers2 .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1". $quebra_linha;
                $headers2 .= "From: " . $emailSender . $quebra_linha;
                $headers2 .= "Return-Path: " . $emailSender . $quebra_linha;
                $headers2 .= "Reply-to: " .  $emailSender . $quebra_linha;

                //sending method
            mail($email, 'bla bla bla', $mensagemHTMLinscrito, $headers2, $emailSender);

        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('This works');</script>"; 


   ?>
```

Comment: *"Is there a better way to show a pop-up message to the user besides using echo+alert?"* - Sure, Ajax/jQuery.

Comment: The reason why it's not working is, you're outputting before header. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: the `header()` inside your `if` would NEVER work anyways. You've performed output (`echo`), which means the headers are already sent. And what does `not work` mean? it pops up the wrong thing? crashes the server? insults your mother?

Comment: It means that this alert inside the echo is not showing,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send out the headers first. So just switch those lines:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Not working');</script>";
header("Location: http://www.blabla.com");
```

to:

```
header("Location: http://www.blabla.com");
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Not working');</script>";
```

That will fix your redirect. However I don't think that the script will been executed, since the browser will directly load the target site. You may prefer this simple script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('Not working');
location.replace("http://www.blabla.com");
</script>
```

Comment: My redirect was working, the alert that wasn't
I changed to this like you said: `header("Location: http://www.blabla.com");
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Not working');</script>";` but still no alert